# Rendering image to texture and preserving blending

Tags: java, opengl

I'm using OpenGL in Java and I've been trying to draw something on the back buffer, copy it onto a texture, and then draw the texture on to the screen.

This is the code I use to do the copying.

```
int textureNumber = GL11.glGenTextures();

GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureNumber);

GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL11.GL_REPEAT);
GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL11.GL_REPEAT);
GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL11.GL_NEAREST);
GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL11.GL_NEAREST);

GL11.glTexEnvf(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL11.GL_REPLACE);

GL11.glCopyTexImage2D
(
  GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL11.GL_RGBA,
  0, 0,
  NewMath.roundUpTwo(width), NewMath.roundUpTwo(height),
  0
);
```

(The roundUpTwo method just rounds the width and height up to the nearest power of 2.)

Now the problem here is that when I re-draw the texture to the screen, it comes out differently than the way it rendered to the backbuffer.

I don't have enough rep to post images directly <_< so here's a screenshot of the behavior.

[image]

Note that the top-left is what happens when I render directly to the screen, the lower-right is what happens when I copy it to a texture and then render the texture.

What I think is happening is that the object I am drawing is made up of a lot of triangles drawn with alpha transparency and with a blending function, and that the CopyTexImage2D function isn't preserving that. I'm not totally sure though because really I have no idea what is happening here.

Is that's what the problem is, how do I fix it? And if it's not, what is and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

> am drawing is made up of a lot of triangles drawn with alpha transparency… and … CopyTexImage2D function isn't preserving that

That's not how it works. Once a picture is drawn, no matter to which framebuffer, all that remains are pixels' values. The geometry used doesn't matter from there on.

The most likely problem is, that you're rendering that texture with the state of the previous drawing steps still enabled and those are "bleeding" through. Hard to tell without seeing the source code you use for drawing of all the different stages, though. I suggest you edit your question, adding that code.